# Rendering issue witth setting a WPF window as an owner of win32 window

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, rendering, win32gui

I set the owner of win32 windows as Application.Current.MainWindow( A WPF window).
Everything worked fine as what i required but when  win32 window is moved over the WPF window
.The win32 dialgos get blurred and win32 window view is mixed with the WPF window nothing comes visible. It altogether mucks the rendering mechanism. So, what is the reason for this issue.

**is it because of that win32 use GDI based rendering and WPF uses Direct3D rendering.**

**if it is so then what is solution for rendering them without interfering each other**